# Circular Textview with bottom rectangle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a circular text-view with a rectangle at bottom for reference purpose here I'm sharing the Sample image and code what I'm trying to achieve

Can anyone help me in create this following screen shot, Thanks in advance.

[image: Trying to create this kind of circular text-view]

Comment: refer this link http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/circular-button-with-icon-and-text-in-android.html

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Thanks for your reference Can you help me in creating bottom rectangular view with text

Comment: dear Brother my work or every member work in http://stackoverflow.com is that 
Solve **BUGS** give a **references**  ***No help for a Make a whole think ok*** 
i give you a reference now your turn to Make Beautiful Layout :)
Best Of Luck

Comment: no write code for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dot"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="sdsjhdsd"
            android:textColor="#ff00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myTv"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:text="sdsjhdsd" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**android:background="@drawable/ic_dot"**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/lightWhite" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#22ff00" />
</shape>
```

**android:background="@drawable/test"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#e60707" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

**RESULT**

[image: ![enter image description here]